# Ubuntu Dash to Dock resizes automatically

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, gnome-shell-extension, dock, dash-to-dock

I'm on 20.04. In the settings of dash to dock I've set the icons to small. When I'm in the settings the dock is fine, but when I close the settings it resizes to the default size (big) and stays like that until I have opened the Settings or GNOME Extensions again.

I reinstalled my Ubuntu because I wasn't able to fix this stupid extension and it behaves the same again!

This is how I want it all the time. It's only like this when I'm in the Extensions option:
[image: This is how i want it all the time! Its only like this when im in the extensions option!!!!!]

How it resizes automatically when Settings / Extensions is not open:
[image: How it resizes automatically when settings / extensions is not open]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because your Icons are not a fixed size, the bar will auto resize to make the Icons fit when a new window is opened.

If you don't have it installed, install `gnome-tweaks`

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

Then bring up the `tweaks` control panel and select the Extensions tab.  Then select the gear on the right of the Dash to Dock to bring up the settings.

[image]

Then turn on the "Fixed icon size" at the bottom.  That should prevent the bar from auto resizing.

[image]